# Parse error when using a xacro property loaded through a yaml file

Tags: ros, yaml, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Environment: Ubuntu 16, ROS Kinetic.

I have a robot_parameters.yaml file with robot parameters:
wheel_separation : 0.235
PI : 3.142

In a xacro file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="robot_name" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:property name="PI" value="${load_yaml('robot_parameters.yaml')}" />

  <link name="left_front_wheel_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.123 0.456 0.101" rpy="${PI/2} 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.101" length = "0.0254"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot>
```

When I do a --check-order on the xacro, I get the following error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict' and 'int' 
when evaluating expression 'PI/2'
XacroException(None,)
```

How would I use an imported name(in this case, PI) via yaml and use it for xacro calculations.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245707/parse-error-when-using-a-xacro-property-loaded-through-a-yaml-file./) by [bluehash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26693/bluehash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2016-10-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With help from a colleague:

When a xacro property is read from a yaml file, it is in a dictionary format.

When used for xacro calculations, the parameter needs to be extracted from the dictionary:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="robot_name" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:property name="a" value="${load_yaml('robot_parameters.yaml')}" />

  <link name="left_front_wheel_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.123 0.456 0.101" rpy="${a['PI']/2} 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.101" length = "0.0254"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [bluehash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26693/bluehash/) with karma: 120 on 2016-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djiglesias](https://answers.ros.org/users/29395/djiglesias/) on 2017-09-13**:
Awesome! Thanks so much. This simplifies the code drastically being able to load in YAML files.